# How to change Jenkins Config.xml properties on Mac

Tags: macos, jenkins, config

Trying to change Jenkins config.xml properties on Mac machine. File is locked. Also tried to unlock the file using Get Info and nothing is working.

Still unable to unlock the file for edit. I do not want to do this from terminal even though that is an option.

Anyone has come across similar situation?

Comment: What you mean by file is locked? You need to use appropriate account to change the file.   The web ui is good enough to make changes to that file; what exactly you are trying to change..

Comment: Hi Jayan, I was trying to set up Configuration and I have set up Security settings from the browser using http://localhost. Upon saving the configuration I lost access to configuration management section. Hence to revert it, one of the posts says to edit the Config.XML file where the security setting were set to true and to make it false. Hence trying to edit that .XML file manually, which system is not allowing me to do.

Comment: Hello, I am unable to replicate the issue you are talking about. I am working on Mac too. The steps that I am following are:  Finder --> Go --> User --> cmd+shift to see Jenkins --> config.xml and I am able to edit the file. Please elaborate on your issue.

Answer (score -3):

If you install Jenkins with the OSX installer, all the files belong to the jenkins user.

So if you want to edit the config.xml file, you have to change the permissions.

The best solution is to use the terminal (if you can):

```
sudo su jenkins - (switch on the jenkins user)
vim config.xml (edit the config.xml file)
```

Comment: I keep on getting as "Jenkins is not a valid user error."

Comment: How did you install Jenkins on your Mac?

Comment: Via Jenkins package .dmg file.

Comment: Can you check which user is running your Jenkins app? ps -aux | grep jenkins

Comment: It is running as Root!!

Comment: So I recommend to change the permission on the config.xml file (with the root user), so you will be able to edit the file with your Mac account.

Comment: Hi Bruno, If you see my question I dont want to do it from terminal. I wanted to try editing the file directly by opening it from finder.

Comment: Hi again,
Yep I saw your post but if the owner of the file is root, you won't be able to edit the file with the finder :(

Comment: If you are able to view the file with the Finder, you can change the permission with a right click, Get info, Sharing & permissions.

Comment: Well see I tried that option as well. But it was acting so weird, able to change the permission but when trying to open the file in Xcode it says you are the owner so you cannot modify.

Comment: Hence I have to post it here.